# EPPlus Calculate method not visible or accessible in Matlab

Tags: .net, matlab, epplus

I'm using EPPlus from Matlab as a .NET assembly:

```
NET.addAssembly(which('EPPlus.dll'));
p = OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage
```

So far, this has been working fairly well for me, and I've been able to successfully use nearly all the functionality in EPPlus. However, I just tried to run the Calculate method to evaluate some formulas, and the Calculate method doesn't appear to be visible. I tried on the workbook, worksheet, and individual cell. None of them work.

```
No appropriate method, property, or field 'Calculate' for class 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange'.
No appropriate method, property, or field 'Calculate' for class 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet'.
No appropriate method, property, or field 'Calculate' for class 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook'.
```

It doesn't show up in the full methods list either.

I double checked back in C#, and the all the sample code works. So I know my DLL should be built properly. Any ideas why this method wouldn't show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels good to finally answer my own tumbleweed question. The answer is to call OfficeOpenXml.CalculationExtension.Calculate on the workbook, worksheet, or cell you want to calculate. Example:

```
NET.addAssembly(which('EPPlus.dll'));
p = OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage;
OfficeOpenXml.CalculationExtension.Calculate(p.Workbook)
```